# Distribution of Omega values modulo m

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Define $\Omega(2^{a_1}3^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k})=a_1+...+a_k$ . I am interested in the density of the values of Omega mod m. If we define the set $S=(x:\Omega(x)\equiv k \text{ mod m})$, I would like to know that the natural density of $S$ is. I suspect it is $\frac{1}{m}$ (So k doesn't matter) but I haven't been able to prove it. I would love to know if anyone is familiar with this problem or if they know any information relating to it. Also, I think that I can prove it for the case m=2 iff I can prove that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{\Omega(k)} $$exists (without bothering about its value). So if anyone has any ideas about how we could prove the existence of this limit sum, I would be very pleased :).

P.S. In my other post "Natural and logarithmic density", I was suggested a general method to prove the existance of 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{f(k)} $$
However it wasn't strong enough for the function $(-1)^{\Omega(k)}$, so I'm trying to dig up other methods.

$(\text{P.S.})^2$ It is probably useful to know that $\Omega$ is completely additive. I.e. $\Omega(ab) = \Omega(a)+\Omega(b)$ Thus $(-1)^{\Omega} $ is a completely multiplicative function.

Comment: $(-1)^{\Omega(n)}$ is the [Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function). $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^{\Omega(k)} = 0$$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem. So your conjecture is correct for $m = 2$. I think it's also correct for larger $m$, but off the top of my head, I don't know how to attack it.